# Access to multiple filtered sites

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have got 100 users who need to access to multiple sites.

My client has around 15 companies, each company has got its own site.
One user may have access to one or more company sites.

When a user login to the main portal, he will have a list of the companies he has access to.

The list will have the names of companies hyperlinked

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

If you have site names on a list, you can use *current user filter web part* to filter list items.